# Sizing a frame to an image in WxPython

Tags: image, wxpython, frame, image-size

I'm making a program with an image for a backdrop, and what I'm trying to do is get the frame to fit the image precisely.

It's easy to initiate the frame with the dimensions of the image:

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 300))
```

but because this also accounts for the borders and header of the window, this isn't entirely accurate. Short of manually adjusting the pixel size (which wouldn't be consistent cross-OS anyway), what can I do?

Edit: I've found an answer, but it looks like I can't self-answer for a few hours. In the meantime...

```
Backdrop = wx.Bitmap("image.png")
self.SetClientSize((Backdrop.GetWidth(), Backdrop.GetHeight()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish the same thing with a sizer, which would also make things easier if you ever need to include other items alongside the image and control how they scale with the frame.

Here's a basic example of a frame that resizes itself to fit an image.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, title, img_path):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, 
                      style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

    image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    image.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img_path))

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    sizer.Add(image)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

    self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Image', '/path/to/file.png')
app.MainLoop()
```